# How does one use GetFinalPathNameByHandle to resolve a symbolic link to a local directory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
std::wstring GetSymbolicLinkTarget(std::wstring const& linkPath)
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    CAutoFile hFile = CreateFile( linkPath.c_str(),
        FILE_READ_EA,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT,
        0);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
    {
        auto rcode = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, path, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
        switch (rcode)
        {
        case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
            return std::wstring();
        case ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY:
            return std::wstring();
        case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            return std::wstring();
        case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
            return std::wstring();
        default:
            break;
        };

        if (path[0] == '\\' && path[1] == '\\' && path[2] == '?' && path[3] == '\\')
            return std::wstring(path + 4, path + MAX_PATH);
        else
            return std::wstring(path, path + MAX_PATH);
    }

    return std::wstring();
}
```

I create a symbolic link like so:

```
e:
cd Projects\ProjectA\IDE_Files
mklink /D src ..
```

Then in some code I call the above function which according to the documents says that:

```
e:\Projects\ProjectA\IDE_Files\src
```

should resolve to:

```
e:\Projects\ProjectA
```

Instead it just returns the input path:

```
e:\Projects\ProjectA\IDE_Files\src
```

The `rcode` result holds the number of characters in the path. Not an error code.

Why does this fail to return the results I expect?

Comment: [To do this, you open the symbolic link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100212-00/?p=14963).  So delete FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Hans! Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Feel free to use what you discovered to complete the Q+A you started.

Comment: Additionally, request 0 access, not `FILE_READ_EA`.  `CreateFile` will actually request `SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` at a minimum, but let it decide this for you. And requesting read-write-delete sharing is just pointless text in your source code, since you're not requesting data access; use 0 for the share mode. Finally, don't include `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` in the attributes. You can't set this attribute; it's set when a reparse point is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer came from [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant):

The problem was primarily due to the use of the `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` flag which does the following:

> The OpenFileById function will either open the file or the reparse
>   point, depending on the use of the FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT flag. [[source]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365505(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here is the final code (with multiple fixes from the comments above.):

```
std::wstring GetSymbolicLinkTarget(std::wstring const& linkPath)
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    CAutoFile hFile = CreateFile( linkPath.c_str(),
        0,
        0,  
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        0);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
    {
        auto rcode = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, path, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
        if (rcode)
        {
            if (path[0] == '\\' && path[1] == '\\' && path[2] == '?' && path[3] == '\\')
                return std::wstring(path + 4, path + rcode);
            else
                return std::wstring(path, path + rcode);
        }
    }

    return std::wstring();
}
```

Comment: `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` return not error code, but length of the string .. in case it return 0, you need call `GetLastError` and already it value compare with `ERROR_*`

Comment: Straight from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx): *"If the function succeeds, the return value is the length of the string received by lpszFilePath, in `TCHAR`s. [...] If the function fails for any other reason, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`."* Besides, your mixture of error reporting (empty string in some error conditions, exceptions in others) is unusual. It adds complexity to the calling code. That's the opposite of what an abstraction is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize the return value didn't contain the error codes. As for the switch... I was using those for debugging to see which code might be happening...